# Should type of events or multiple clients be the channels in redis?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I am developing a multi client real time analytics application, where a client has number of users which perform some actions.
For example `agentJoined`, `agentLeft`, `customerJoined`, `customerLeft`, `newCustomerAdded` etc. up to some 40 events. Clients can range to any number. So what should be the Redis Pub/Sub pattern? Shall client be the channel and event types are published as payload or event types must be the channel and client information is sent as payload.

Comment: I think it should be `client` wise, because partitioning and distributing would be a lot easier as suppose to `event` wise which might delay the events for different clients because there will be a lot of same events for different clients.

Comment: Are you only using Redis for messaging?

Comment: Yes for Pub/Sub.